# Screen fixing in html/css

Tags: html

if you click and hold the left hand corner of the stackoverflow webpage and drag it to make a smaller browser the screen does nothing with it's elements it just becomes a smaller screen as parts drop off. This is what I want to achieve. Probably easy, however I can't get it to do it on my small web app. If I do this the centre Div and it's containing text start overlapping other elements etc. I thought position: fixed; might help but that drags the centre div across the screen.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just set a specific with to `<body>`, for example:

```
body {
    width: 900px;
}
```

[**Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/T229g/)

You can also try `min-width` instead of `width`.

Comment: that's it Many thanks. I think the confusion was that I am using Rails and this sets a default application file with the overall page body. Thats where I made the change and it works. I also added a min-height. This will only ever be used on a PC not a mobile device. Thanks again.

Answer (score -1):

If you add a `<div>` to everything in the `<body>` with a width it will become fixed instead of liquid.

like this:

```
<div style="width: 1366">
<body>
    blah blah
</body> 
</div>
```

Comment: Placing `<body>` inside a `<div>` is invalid. CSS `width` property needs units, e.g. `1366px`. No need to modify structure, `<body>` element can be styled like any `<div>`. Inline styles should avoided, because of [separation of content and presentation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Separation_of_presentation_and_content).

Comment: Thank you for enlightening me. For some reason I always did it like this.